# Как реализовать сворачивание и разворичивание строки таблицы?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

У меня такая проблема, что я не могу реализовать сворачивание и разворачивание строки таблицы, у меня выходит что. В основном div блоки, потому что в этих блоках должны иметь статичная блок с днными не в виде таблицы новой. Но у меня получается что этот блок добавляется внутрь следующего столбца. Зачем я не использую другие подходы, потому что мне нужно чтобы при выборе строки потом из бд исходя из id подгружились данные через ajax. Но это на будущее. Но сейчас мне нужно реализовать такой вод блок после нажатие на строку

```js
$('.header').click(function(){
 $(this).toggleClass('expand')
    .append('<div>Привет</div>')
})
```

```css
table, tr, td, th
{
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
.header:hover{
  cursor: pointer
}
.header .sign:after{
  content: '-'
}
.header.expand .sign:after{
  content: '+'
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border='0'>
  <tr>
    <th>Класс</th>
    <th>код</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class='header expand'>
    <td><span class='sign'></span> Мебель</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='header expand'>
    <td><span class='sign'></span> Электроника</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='header expand'>
    <td><span class='sign'></span> Бытовая химия</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что то типо того?

```js
$('.header').click(function(){
  if($(this).hasClass('expand')){  
  $(this).toggleClass('expand');
  $(this).after('<tr class="child"><td>blahblah</td><td>4</td></tr>'); 
 }else{  
  $(this).toggleClass('expand');
  $(this).next().remove();
 }   
})
```

```css
table, tr, td, th
{
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
.header:hover{
  cursor: pointer
}
.header .sign:after{
  content: '-'
}
.header.expand .sign:after{
  content: '+'
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border='0'>
  <tr>
    <th>Класс</th>
    <th>код</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class='header expand'>
    <td><span class='sign'></span> Мебель</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='header expand'>
    <td><span class='sign'></span> Электроника</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='header expand'>
    <td><span class='sign'></span> Бытовая химия</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Ну не совсем, надо чтобы она не создавала столбец, а добавляла строку. То есть внизу должно привет оказаться. Во тпримерно так http://jsfiddle.net/nc8bt9ss/ Только нужно чтобы не было значально tr а они динамично появлялись. Потому что потом я хочу выводить данные в ajax, чтобы страница не тормозилась при выводе больих данных

Comment: А как сделать так чтобы она вниз уходила а не направо?

Comment: @Руслан обновил ответ, посмотрите оно или не то

Comment: вместо этого `$(this).parent().find('.child').remove()` я бы написал так : `$(this).next().remove();`

Comment: @RostyslavKuzmovych +

Answer (score 0):

Не уверен в синтаксисе, в общем либо добавь див непосредственно в html код, и его уже хайди, а не апенди, либо сделай дополнительную проверку

```js
$('.header').click(function() {
  if (!$(this).hasClass('expand'))
    $(this).toggleClass('expand').append('<div>Привет</div>');
  else
    $(this).toggleClass('expand').remove('<div>Привет</div>');
})
```